# Send print data to TIJ printer from raspberry pi instead of the factory software

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, wireshark, software-design, ethernet

Hello i have this SOJET ELFIN 1S TIJ printer (https://sojet.net/en/equipment/elfin-i/) and sojet says that it doesn't support dynamic text. They way u do it is u type in the touch screen what text should be printed than it prints it.

But with my project there will be parts that each part will have a different text label that goes on it so that wouldn't work.

there is also an Ethernet port on the unit and pc software that i installed so you can type it on a pc than print it from there but again only static text.

So my question is, would there be a way to "sniff" the ethernet  communication that the pc sends to the unit and than mimic that language from a raspberry pi to send dynamic data to the printer? Wireshark?

I have tried to use wireshark but im a bit new to understand that. see attached[Picture of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKs1z.png) screenshot

Comment: If you don't get any good wireshark suggestions another option might be to reverse engineer the PC software using a tool like Ghidra.  Also, have you done a web search to see if  someone else already did either of those?  Back in ancient times most printers could be controlled for ASCII text by sending old HP and Epson command sets but that was 25 years ago -- I haven't bypassed the OS printer drivers since then.